# TYPO3 - How to configure TYPO3 path access?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

I want to configure path access rules for my TYPO3, for example: www.domin.cn/admin/news/ instead of www.domin.cn/index.php?id=14, what should I do?

Comment: What version of TYPO3 are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TYPO3 version < v9 you have to install an extension like e.g. realurl: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/realurl

With TYPO3 version v9 the url handling went into the core.